# Java factorial method

Tags: java, methods, factorial

I'm looking for a little assistance on my factorial method. I can't seem to get it to sum correctly.

I'm only required to take in any number between 1 and 12 and then sum the multiplication...and return the summation.

User selects: 5
1*2*3*4*5 = 120

```
package cit130hmw07_laginess;

    import java.util.Scanner;

 public class CIT130HMW07_Laginess 
 {


   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Please select a number between 0 and 12:");
     int factorial = input.nextInt();

     sumFactorials(factorial);
     int facSum = sumFactorials(factorial);
     System.out.println("");
     System.out.println("Your results are: " + facSum);
     System.out.println("");

   }//main

   public static int sumFactorials(int factorial)
   {

      int results = 1;
      for(int i = 1; i <= factorial; i++)
         results = results * factorial;

         return results;

   }//factorials
}//class
```

Comment: not `results = results * factoral` but rather `results = i * results;` Learn to use a debugger as this will show you your error.

Comment: Also _"I can't seem to get it to sum correctly"_ -- there are no sums involved, only products.

Comment: Do you want to get sum of factorials ? like 5! =120 and you want to get 1+2+0 =3 . Is my assumption correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Some small flaws in your code. Look for the mistakes in comment under respective statement, and their corrections in code following. Notice the extra lines which were not required. You should always write code with as minimum lines as possible, without compromising the readability (i.e. with proper indenting as well).

```
package cit130hmw07_laginess;

import java.util.Scanner;

 public class CIT130HMW07_Laginess 
 {


   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Please select a number between 0 and 12:");
     int factorial = input.nextInt();

     //sumFactorials(factorial);
     //this line was not required. 

     int facSum = sumFactorials(factorial);

     //System.out.println("");
     //not required when you can use delimiters inside println

     System.out.println("\nYour results are: " + facSum + "\n");

     //System.out.println("");
     //same as before.

   }//main

   public static int sumFactorials(int factorial)
   {

      int results = 1;
      for(int i = 1; i <= factorial; i++)
         //results = results * factorial;
         //this was where your code was not correct.             

         //Correct : 
         results = results * i;
         return results;

   }//factorials
}//class
```

Inside println, I have used delimiters (look for **\n**) to minimize printing statements.

Answer (score 0):

check comments for your mistakes:

1. the only correction is:

   results=results*i;
   rest were some unnecessary stuff;

package cit130hmw07_laginess;

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

 public class CIT130HMW07_Laginess 
 {


   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     System.out.println("Please select a number between 0 and 12:");
     int factorial = input.nextInt();

     //sumFactorials(factorial);
     int facSum = sumFactorials(factorial);
     //System.out.println("");
     System.out.println("Your results are: " + facSum);
     //System.out.println("");

   }//main

   public static int sumFactorials(int factorial)
   {

      int results = 1;
      for(int i = 1; i <= factorial; i++)
         //results = results * factorial;
          results=results*i;

         return results;

   }//factorials
}//class
```

Answer (score -1):

write a jave method called factorila that calulates and returns the factorial of a given non-negative integer(0!=1).
inculde your mehtod into java program that print the factorial of the numbers from 0 to 10 via invoking the method factorial .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).